# Unable to get logs of application over rsyslog server

Tags: server, rsyslog

I used this template on my server to arrange logs by the client hostname:

```
$template TmplAuth, "/var/log/%HOSTNAME%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log"
```

and on client end:

```
*.*@10.x.x.x:514
```

The problem is that the logs only consist of `sshlog.cron` logs and `compiz` logs.

How can I get the client log of auth.log, syslog, and logs based on application by the client hostname?

Comment: formatted code, clarified question , fixed grammar

Comment: Reworded for clarity.